# QWebengineView : Disable Ctrl+mouse wheel

Tags: qt, qwebengineview, qwebenginepage, qwebengine

Is it possible to disable zooming(ctrl+mousewheel) of html content loaded in QWebEngineView. I tried

```
qputenv("QTWEBENGINE_CHROMIUM_FLAGS", "--enable-blink-features=ShadowDOMV0,CustomElementsV0,--disable-pinch");
```

it is not working.

Note: We are building a desktop application.

Comment: Subclass `QWebEngineView` and override relevant protected virtual event method. Or, install event filter and block events.

Comment: OK will try. But are there any chromium flags/switches to disable zoom. I could not find any relevant switches. https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/

Comment: Those env variables quite possibly are not used with an embedded chromium engine, or they're disabled on purpose maybe. If they were enabled, they'd need to be documented for any Qt app using the module, and still have surprised users and odd bug reports...

Comment: Any success? I've incidentally also been looking into this, with not much success so far.

Comment: Did you find the answer? Can you share it please

Comment: No. Could not find any answer. I was moved to a different project. So not pursuing. Apologies.